# Make HTTP Request in .net-core on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core

Is this feature supported at the moment?
I don't want to use mono, just using .net-core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Http Client in with System.Net.Http

Comment: ah, Jesus, was looking at `System.Web`